# Adding Rows based on Date Change

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, rows

I am trying to add rows in a sheet every time the date is changed. 
So for example the row below:

```
1/1/2020
1/1/2020
2/2/2020
2/2/2020
2/2/2020
3/3/2020
3/3/2020
3/3/2020
```

Here is the code that I have tried,

```
Public Sub InsertRow()

Dim lastRow, chkRw, I As Integer
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
chkRw = lastRow - 1

For I = lastRow To 2 Step -1
      If Cells(lastRow, 1) <> Cells(chkRw, 1) Then
      Cells(lastRow, 1).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
     End If
Next


End Sub
```

I am new to this and have been doing a lot of research. However, I can not figure it out. Any suggestions would be super helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use I not `lastRow` inside the loop

```
Public Sub InsertRow()


    With ActiveSheet
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim I As Long
        For I = lastRow To 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(I, 1) <> .Cells(I - 1, 1) Then
                .Rows(I).Insert shift:=xlDown
            End If
        Next
    End With


End Sub
```